# java Robot right click not working

Tags: java, awtrobot

I am building a virtual controller so a buddy with a disability can play PC games.  WASD are working fine. But I also need it to simulate right-click.  I have `BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK` in my `mousePressed` and `mouseReleased` events but it does not actually do anything.

My code is below.  I know it is sloppy but I am trying to figure this out first:

```
public class GameController2 extends JFrame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, ComponentListener{
    public JLabel CoordsLabel;
    public JLabel buttonWA;
    public JLabel buttonW;
    public JLabel buttonWD;
    public JLabel buttonA;
    public JLabel buttonD;
    public JLabel buttonAS;
    public JLabel buttonS;
    public JLabel buttonSD;
    public JFrame controlFrame;
    public int mMovedX;
    public int mMovedY;
    public Robot robot;
    public ImageIcon cIconOver, cIcon, rIcon, rIconOver, brIcon, brIconOver, bIcon, bIconOver, blIcon, blIconOver, lIcon, lIconOver, tlIcon, tlIconOver, tIcon, tIconOver, trIcon, trIconOver;
    public int fWidth;
    public int fHeight;

    public ArrayList<JLabel> buttons;
    public int gX = 0;
    public int gY = 0;

    public Icon origImg;

    public GameController2(){
        controlFrame = new JFrame();
        GridBagLayout gridbag = new GridBagLayout();
        controlFrame.setLayout(gridbag);
        controlFrame.setSize(300,300);

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        tlIcon = new ImageIcon("tlIconTest.png");
        buttonWA = new JLabel();
        buttonWA.setName("buttonWA");
        //buttonWA.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        buttonWA.setOpaque(true);
        buttonWA.addMouseListener(this);
        buttonWA.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        gridbag.setConstraints(buttonWA, c);
        controlFrame.add(buttonWA);
        buttonWA.setIcon(tlIcon);

        tIcon = new ImageIcon("tIconTest.png");
        buttonW = new JLabel("W");
        buttonW.setName("buttonW");
        buttonW.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        buttonW.setOpaque(true);
        buttonW.addMouseListener(this);
        buttonW.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        gridbag.setConstraints(buttonW, c);
        controlFrame.add(buttonW);
        buttonW.setIcon(tIcon);

        trIcon = new ImageIcon("trIconTest.png");
        buttonWD = new JLabel("W+D");
        buttonWD.setName("buttonWD");
        buttonWD.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        buttonWD.setOpaque(true);
        buttonWD.addMouseListener(this);
        buttonWD.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 0;
        gridbag.setConstraints(buttonWD, c);
        controlFrame.add(buttonWD);
        buttonWD.setIcon(trIcon);

        lIcon = new ImageIcon("lIconTest.png");
        buttonA = new JLabel("A");
        buttonA.setName("buttonA");
        buttonA.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        buttonA.setOpaque(true);
        buttonA.addMouseListener(this);
        buttonA.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        gridbag.setConstraints(buttonA, c);
        controlFrame.add(buttonA);
        buttonA.setIcon(lIcon);

        cIcon = new ImageIcon("rMouseOrig.png");
        CoordsLabel = new JLabel();
        CoordsLabel.setName("CoordsLabel");
        //CoordsLabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        CoordsLabel.setOpaque(true);
        CoordsLabel.addMouseListener(this);
        CoordsLabel.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        gridbag.setConstraints(CoordsLabel, c);
        controlFrame.add(CoordsLabel);
        CoordsLabel.setIcon(cIcon);

        rIcon = new ImageIcon("rIconTest.png");
        buttonD = new JLabel();
        buttonD.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        buttonD.setOpaque(true);
        buttonD.setName("buttonD");
        buttonD.addMouseListener(this);
        buttonD.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 1;
        gridbag.setConstraints(buttonD, c);
        controlFrame.add(buttonD);
        buttonD.setIcon(rIcon);

        blIcon = new ImageIcon("blIconTest.png");
        buttonAS = new JLabel();
        buttonAS.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        buttonAS.setOpaque(true);
        buttonAS.setName("buttonAS");
        buttonAS.addMouseListener(this);
        buttonAS.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        gridbag.setConstraints(buttonAS, c);
        controlFrame.add(buttonAS);
        buttonAS.setIcon(blIcon);

        bIcon = new ImageIcon("bIconTest.png");
        buttonS = new JLabel("S");
        buttonS.setName("buttonS");
        buttonS.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        buttonS.setOpaque(true);
        buttonS.addMouseListener(this);
        buttonS.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 2;
        gridbag.setConstraints(buttonS, c);
        controlFrame.add(buttonS);
        buttonS.setIcon(bIcon);

        brIcon = new ImageIcon("brIconTest.png");
        buttonSD = new JLabel("");
        buttonSD.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        buttonSD.setOpaque(true);
        buttonSD.setName("buttonSD");
        buttonSD.addMouseListener(this);
        buttonSD.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 2;
        gridbag.setConstraints(buttonSD, c);
        //controlFrame.add(buttonSD);
        buttonSD.setIcon(brIcon);

        controlFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        controlFrame.setVisible(true);
        controlFrame.setFocusableWindowState(false);

        rIconOver = new ImageIcon("rIconOverTest.png");
        brIconOver = new ImageIcon("brIconOverTest.png");
        bIconOver = new ImageIcon("bIconOverTest.png");
        blIconOver = new ImageIcon("blIconOverTest.png");
        lIconOver = new ImageIcon("lIconOverTest.png");
        tlIconOver = new ImageIcon("tlIconOverTest.png");
        tIconOver = new ImageIcon("tIconOverTest.png");
        trIconOver = new ImageIcon("trIconOverTest.png");
        cIconOver = new ImageIcon("rMouseOver.png");

        try{
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e){
//
    }

    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e){
        //
    }

    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e){
        //
    }

    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e){
        //
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
            JLabel label = (JLabel)e.getSource();
            String name = label.getName();

            if(name == "buttonSD"){
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
                origImg = buttonSD.getIcon();
                buttonSD.setIcon(brIconOver);
            } else if(name == "buttonS"){
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
                origImg = buttonS.getIcon();
                buttonS.setIcon(bIconOver);
            } else if (name == "buttonWD"){
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
                origImg = buttonWD.getIcon();
                buttonWD.setIcon(trIconOver);
            } else if(name == "buttonW"){
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
                origImg = buttonW.getIcon();
                buttonW.setIcon(tIconOver);
            } else if(name == "buttonWA"){
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
                origImg = buttonWA.getIcon();
                buttonWA.setIcon(tlIconOver);
            }else if(name == "buttonA"){
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
                origImg = buttonA.getIcon();
                buttonA.setIcon(lIconOver);
            } else if(name == "buttonAS"){
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
                origImg = buttonAS.getIcon();
                buttonAS.setIcon(blIconOver);
            } else if(name == "buttonD"){
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
                origImg = buttonD.getIcon();
                buttonD.setIcon(rIconOver);
            } else if(name == "CoordsLabel"){
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
            }

              System.out.println(label);
        }

    @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent m){
        //
    }

        @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
        //
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        if((JLabel)e.getSource() != CoordsLabel){
            JLabel tmpLabel = (JLabel)e.getSource();
            tmpLabel.setIcon(origImg);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK);

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        //
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new GameController2();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK is the right-click? it sounds more like the middle button of the mouse, try with BUTTON2_DOWN_MASK

Comment: @Dazak as far as i remember with awt.Robot: BUTTON2 - middle, BUTTON 3 - right

Comment: Everything I have read says 3...

Comment: I would go for 2 beeing the RMB and 3 middle one.

Comment: I tested 2...still nothing...

Comment: try BUTTON2_MASK

Comment: @Antoniossss Nothing

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is working. It can be seen if you add some debug information like this:

```
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
    System.out.println("ReleasingMouseButton: " + e.getButton());
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK);

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    System.out.println("PressingMouseButton: " + e.getButton());
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK);
}
```

Now if you click one of labels, you will see that you will be trapped in click-release event loop. So robot in fact is clicking for you like you wanted (or rather like you programmed it to do so).

Slice of output:

> ReleasingMouseButton: 3 PressingMouseButton: 3 ReleasingMouseButton: 3
>   PressingMouseButton: 3 ReleasingMouseButton: 3 PressingMouseButton: 3
>   ReleasingMouseButton: 3 PressingMouseButton: 3 ReleasingMouseButton: 3
>   PressingMouseButton: 3 ReleasingMouseButton: 3 PressingMouseButton: 3
>   ReleasingMouseButton: 3 PressingMouseButton: 3 ReleasingMouseButton: 3
>   PressingMouseButton: 3 ReleasingMouseButton: 3 PressingMouseButton: 3
>   ReleasingMouseButton: 3 PressingMouseButton: 3 ReleasingMouseButton: 3
>   PressingMouseButton: 3

I doubt that this is what you wanted, so you will need to add some extra logic to it (eg, checking which mouse button was clicked)

Comment: So how do I get it to send a right click to the focused window?

Comment: I am guessing Java can't since it will be out of the JVM?

Comment: I think that you should move your mouse button to the destination using robot#mouseMove and then click and release.